# RecyclerView not displaying layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a recycler view which is not displaying a specific layout. I know that the layout is the problem, because I've tried with different layouts and they are being displayed. I don't get any errors in the console for the bad layout.

That layout is structured as follows:

```
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/border_color"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%">

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I see it rendered properly, but probably is something wrong with it. I want that each of my recycler's items to have 30% height, that's why I'm using `app:layout_heightPercent="30%"`. If I remove the outer layout the inner layout will take all the space. How can I achieve this 30% height, because clearly this is not working.

Comment: Why do you have two PercentRelativeLayout? Nothing will really show if you do that

Comment: I explained it in the question. And that's not my whole layout. I have multiple things in the inner layout.  The only reason I used 2 of them is because if I only used the inner one when I preview it, it's taking all the space not only 30%

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

I have set height as 100dp for parent PercentRelativeLayout. It is working for me.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#888888"
            app:layout_heightPercent="30%">

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, give an id to the outer layout, or whatever layout your recycler items might have `outer`,

define it in your holder:

```
outer = (PercentRelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.outer);
```

and inside your `onBindViewHolder` set your height programatically:

```
Display display = ((Activity)ctx).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            //int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;

            ((MyRecyclerHolder) holder).outer.getLayoutParams().height = height/3;(or whatever ratio you want)
```